# Erase words from a string (in C++)

Tags: c++

I want to delete some words from a string but my code doesn't work . I don't have any errors or warnings , but I'm thinking that my string becomes empty.  Could someone help me with this? I tried to convert my initial strings into 2 vectors, so that I can navigate more easily then

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        string s("Somewhere down the road");
        string t("down");
        istringstream iss(s);
        vector <string> plm;
        vector <string> plm2;


        do
        {
            string sub;
            iss >> sub;
            plm.push_back(sub);

        } while (iss);


    for(unsigned int i=0 ; i<plm.size();i++){
    cout<<plm[i];}


        istringstream ist(t);


        do
        {
            string subb;
            ist >> subb;
            plm2.push_back(subb);

        } while (ist);


    for(int i=0;i<plm.size();i++){
    for(int j=0;j<plm2.size();i++){
    {if (plm[i]==plm2[j])
        plm.erase(plm.begin()+j);}}}


    for(int i=0 ; i<plm.size();i++)
    cout<<plm[i];


    }
```

Comment: You never increment `j`. And you should learn how your debugger works.

Answer (score 3):

Warning: this is really just a comment that's too long to fit in a comment field. Oh, and a bit of a rant at that.

I'm sure glad we have these modern languages to make life so much easier than it was decades ago. Consider, for example, what this job looked like an the long-since moribund SNOBOL 4 programming language:

```
    s = 'somewhere down the road'
del s 'down' =                     :s(del)
    OUTPUT = s
```

God, it's nice that we've since made so much progress that we don't have to deal with 3 whole lines of code, and we can now do the job with only 52 lines instead (oh, except that the 52 lines don't actually work, but let's ignore that for the moment).

I guess, in fairness, we can do the job a little more compactly in C++ though. One obvious way would be with `std::remove_copy`, some stream iterators, and a stringstream or two:

```
std::istringstream input("somewhere down the road");
std::string del_str("down");

std::istream_iterator<std::string> in(input), end;

std::ostringstream result;

std::remove_copy(in, end, std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(result, " "), del_str);

std::cout << result.str();
```

Comment: i think you forgot the predicate in the `std::remove_copy_if` function or is this a different kind of function?.

Comment: @bkVnet: Oops--yeah, I did leave something out.

Comment: When i tried to compile this it give me a compiler error *"term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments"*, i think the predicate should be a function taking a string as parameter and return a bool. I'm not sure if this is the behaviour in C++ 11 though(probably you can use lambda expression there) since my compiler doesn't support it. Any way +1, i get the general idea.

Comment: @bkVnet: You probably need to reload the page. Originally I'd accidentally written it as `remove_copy_if`, but really meant to use `remove_copy` instead (and rewrote it to that ~30 minutes before your comment).

Comment: Oh yes, i see. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There is no benefit in converting to vector - string itself already provides all that is necessary for what you want to do. Anyway, do it this way:

```cpp
vector<char> v;
v.assign(s.c_str(), s.c_str() + s.length()); // without... 
v.assign(s.c_str(), s.c_str() + s.length() + ); // including...
    // ... terminating null character
```

Now it gets easy:

```cpp
size_t pos = s.find(t);
if(pos != string::npos)
{
    s.erase(pos, t.length());
}
```

This does not care, however, about leaving multiple whitespace or if t is not an entire word within s (e. g. `t = "down"; s = "I'm going to downtown.";` would result in `s == "I'm going to town."`), but you did not do so either...

Answer (score 0):

First problem is, if `std::string::erase` is called only with the beginning position, it erases everything until the end of string.

Second problem is, that the code will just erase all letters which are in the second string, one by one. I.e. not the entire word - for that, you would need to check if the entire word matches, and only then erase (the entire length of the word). Ask yourself - what will happen in the code, if e.g. the first two letters will match, but not the rest of the word?

Answer (score 0):

In your second `for` loop you never incremented `j` and inside the `if (plm[i]==plm2[j])` block you used `j` instead of `i` as your offset in `erase()`.

```
for(int i=0;i<plm.size();i++) 
{
    for(int j=0;j<plm2.size();j++)//here you need to increment j
    {
        if (plm[i]==plm2[j])
            plm.erase(plm.begin()+i);//here the offset should be i
    }

}
```

Another thing don't use a `do...while` loop to read from the `stringstream` and push back on the vector. If the reading fails you will be pushing invalid data to the vector, instead try something like:

```
 string sub;
 while(iss >> sub;)
      plm.push_back(sub);//only if reading is successful

 ...//do the same for the other istringstream too
```

Answer (score -1):

You do not increment j this is the first thing I saw on your code. Write it correctly then if it still doesnt work, then ask!